# inline-block last item wrapping, but there is enough space

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my menu to the right side using text-align:right on the parent and display: inline-block on menu. (see example: http://codepen.io/sanns/pen/WQjRoj?editors=110)

I also want items in menu align left, so I used `text-align:left` on `li`. But the problem is that the last item for some reason wraps despite there's enough width for all elements.

Why is it happening?

```css
.navg {
  display: inline-block;
  /* to aplly parents text-align*/
  text-align: left;
  /* align children*/
}

.navg__item {
  margin-right: 2.5%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-9 text-right">
  <ul class="navg">
    <li class="navg__item navg__item--active"><a href="#" class="navg__link">Главная</a></li>
    <li class="navg__item"><a href="#" class="navg__link">Услуги</a></li>
    <li class="navg__item"><a href="#" class="navg__link">On-line заказ</a></li>
    <li class="navg__item"><a href="#" class="navg__link">О компании</a></li>
    <li class="navg__item"><a href="#" class="navg__link">Контакты</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.navg__item {
    margin-right: 2.5%;
}
```

If you look at that 2.5% , that is the reason your item is going to new line.
% of margins are calculated against width of the element.

If you did something like

```
.navg__item {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

It should work.

Some more information here : http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties

Especially this part

> **Percentage** -
>   The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well. If the containing block's width depends on this element, then the resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.

Comment: Oh, thanks! So confusing when width is calculated by content, and contents percentage is calculated by parent :P

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `display: inline-block` from `.navg` class

```css
.navg { /* to aplly parents text-align*/  
    text-align: left; /* align children*/
}

.navg__item {
        margin-right: 1%;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-9 text-right" >
  <ul class="navg" >
    <li class="navg__item navg__item--active" ><a href="#" class="navg__link">Главная</a></li>
    <li class="navg__item"><a href="#" class="navg__link">Услуги</a></li>
    <li class="navg__item"><a href="#" class="navg__link">On-line заказ</a></li>
    <li class="navg__item"><a href="#" class="navg__link">О компании</a></li>
    <li class="navg__item"><a href="#" class="navg__link">Контакты</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```